# A VM is provisioned in Azure with only internal IP. For CI/CD, VSTS needs to connect to VM

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-virtual-machine, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

A VM is provisioned in Azure with an internal IP only for security reasons. For CI/CD, VSTS needs to connect to VM, but i am seeing connection time out and naturally because VM is behind organization firewall. In order to get the firewal opened we need source IP's of VSTS which is PAAS. How do i figure out source IP ranges? Or is there is any other way to connect to VM?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent?

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s better to add current Hosted agent IP to the firewall IP list during the build/release. To get the current using Hosted agent IP, you can use this PowerShell (Check Allow scripts to access OAuth token option in build/release definition):

```
param (
    [string]$RestAddress,
    [string]$Token
    )
$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f 'test',$Token)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth)}
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RestAddress -headers $headers -Method Get
Write-Host $result.value
```

Arguments:

```
-RestAddress https://[account].vsdtl.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/vslabs/ipaddress -Token $(System.AccessToken)
```

There is an article about Hosted agent IP ranges, but a new xml file will be uploaded every Wednesday (Pacific Time) with the new planned IP address ranges. New IP address ranges will be effective on the following Monday (Pacific Time). So you need to update the firewall IP range frequently.

[What IP Addresses are used by Hosted Build?](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/ip-addresses-used-hosted-build/)

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore. Seems like the IP endpoint has been deprecated.